# Gulp not compiling but getting error ReferenceError: runSequence is not defined

Tags: javascript, gulp

### Question

What should I modify in my code to get these two tasks to build in sequence?

---

### Background

I have never had this problem before with gulp, but now that I want to run two tasks in sequence, it is not working properly. I have two tasks previously set up.

```
gulp.task('copyAllFiles', function() {
    //PHP files
    gulp.src('src/*.php')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    //childtheme screenshot
    gulp.src('src/screenshot.png')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('sass2css', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

I then added a "build" task to run both

#### gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
    runSequence(['copyAllFiles', 'sass2css'], callback);
});
```

But now getting this error

```
ReferenceError: runSequence is not defined
```

Comment: What is this **runSequence**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `runSequence`, you'll need to install that dependency and `require` it into your gulp file:

**Install**

```
npm install --save-dev run-sequence
```

**Gulp file**

```
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');
```

Comment: Unrelated but related, I would also suggest looking at yarn package manager: `yarn add run-sequence --dev`